# What are those shiny things?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Normally those appear around place with collectibles but for some reason here there is nothing. Found multiple in High Isle.

Any idea what they are?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Pick it up and find out.

> This highlight is typically used for collectibles that are part of a zone's "Museum Quest".

> They originally started with the Orsinium DLC, where you're supposed to bring back artifacts of Orcish history to the House of the Glory of the Orsimer (which is essentially a museum, therefore coining said term).

> In short, that's a task where you're supposed to find items hidden throughout the world (for Hew's Bane/Thieves Guild DLC) or in the local zone (most other content) and bring them to a central place related to the associated DLC or chapter.

**Edit:** I might have misinterpreted your question. If you see this, there should be something to interact with. If it isn't there, it's possible your client might think it's actually below the ground or some other obstacle. Try relogging and this might fix it.

Comment: Hello... indeed a missinterpretation :). And your response is in general correct. Is probably my fault for not making it clearer. I did say "normally those appear around places with collectibles". But in this case, in High Isle... there is nothing. Found 4 places so far. I figure that if one is bugged (like the lute in Greymoor for that first week)... would be one. 4 seems rather strange. I did try relog etc.

Comment: @zozo Okay, that sounds really broken. Haven't tried to collect them so far though.